# Using wx.CallLater in wxPython

Tags: python, date, loops, time, wxpython

I'm trying to make an object that handles basic time related functions. I want it so when any of the attributes (e.g. **self.Time** ) are referenced they are up to date. However, for some reason **wx.CallLater(1000, self.Tick)** doesn't seem to be updating the attributes. It will only print **self.Time** once, as opposed to every second (like I want it to).

How would I go about getting the behavior I desire? Should I use something besides **wx.CallLater(1000, self.Tick)**?

Snippet :

```
import wx, re, time, win32api, calendar

class TimeDate :

    def __init__ (self) :

        self.Tick()

    def Tick (self) :

        self.Year     = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
        self.Month    = int(time.strftime("%m"))
        self.Calendar = calendar.month(self.Year, self.Month)
        self.Date     = time.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')
        self.Time     = time.strftime('%I:%M %S %p')

        print self.Time

        wx.CallLater(1000, self.Tick)
```

Comment: It might be that your error is somewhere else.  Can you post a complete (but minimal) example that demonstrates the issue you are having?  We need to see more code.

Comment: Are you creating a instance of `TimeDate`? You have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is wx.Timer, not wx.CallAfter or wx.CallLater. See the following tutorial on timers for more information:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

Both of the those "Call*" methods only fire once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wx.CallAfter` instead - `wx.CallLater` [is a class](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) and should be used differently.

`wx.CallAfter`, on the other hand, seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score -2):

I think both `wx.CallAfter` and `wx.CallLater` are called only once.....