# wxpython using time.sleep() without blocking complete GUI

Tags: user-interface, time, wxpython, blocking

I want to change the text displayed in my GUI at specific time intervals. After a lot of approaches, I find that, specifically to my requirements, I must use `time.sleep()` instead of `wx.Timer`, but `time.sleep()` freeze the complete GUI. Here's an example of my code:

```
import wx
import time

DWELL_TIMES = [1, 2, 1, 3]
SCREEN_STRINGS = ['nudge nudge', 'wink wink', 'I bet she does', 'say no more!']

class DM1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        text_display = wx.StaticText(panel, pos = (400, 150))

        for dwell_time in DWELL_TIMES:
            text_display.SetLabel(SCREEN_STRINGS[dwell_time])
            time.sleep(float(DWELL_TIMES[dwell_time]))


app = wx.App()
DM1Frame = DM1(None, size = (800, 600))
DM1Frame.Center()
DM1Frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Does somebody know why this happen, and how to make the GUI doesn't block?
I guess that `Threading` could help me, doesn't it? If it does, which is the correct way to put threads inside this code? Is there an alternative to `Threading`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others, `wx.CallAfter` and `wx.CallLater` are your friends. Study them and learn them. Here is a complete, working example using `wx.CallLater`. I included other refactoring as I saw fit.

```
import wx

DATA = [
    (1, 'nudge nudge'),
    (2, 'wink wink'),
    (1, 'I bet she does'),
    (3, 'say no more!'),
]

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.index = 0
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        duration, label = DATA[self.index]
        self.text.SetLabel(label)
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(DATA)
        wx.CallLater(int(duration * 1000), self.update)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(None)
    frame = Frame()
    frame.SetTitle('Example')
    frame.SetSize((400, 300))
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `Study them and learn them` ....for a second there, I thought S.Lott had come back :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [time.sleep()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep), you see that it basically blocks execution of that thread for the specified interval. The problem is that currently your GUI has only a single thread, so if you block the thread then you block ALL execution in that thread. This means, as you've experienced, that the GUI is unusable during the sleep.

Even using threading, the `time.sleep()` call can't be in the same thread as the GUI, thus trying to get your GUI to refresh after the sleep is over will be very complicated. Beyond that, it's basically reimplementing `wx.Timer`! No use redoing something that's already been done for you.

It seems to me that your question should be less "how do I make sleeps work?" and more "Why isn't `wx.Timer` working properly?" Please explain the problem you're having with `wx.Timer` in detail. Why won't it work? Maybe post some code. My guess is you probably aren't binding the `wx.EVT_TIMER` properly. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/).

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the correct way to put threads inside this code?

Although using `wx.Timer` is the correct solution to this simplified example, if your real goal is to know how to use a worker thread to do long tasks and give updates to your main GUI without freezing your whole application, here's how:

```
import wx
import threading
import time

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    DWELL_TIMES = [1, 2, 1, 3]
    SCREEN_STRINGS = ['nudge nudge', 'wink wink', 'I bet she does', 'say no more!']

    def __init__(self, window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def run(self):
        for i in range(len(WorkerThread.DWELL_TIMES)):
            wx.CallAfter(self.window.set_text, WorkerThread.SCREEN_STRINGS[i])
            time.sleep(float(WorkerThread.DWELL_TIMES[i]))
        wx.CallAfter(self.window.close)


class DM1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text_display = wx.StaticText(panel, pos = (400, 150))
        self.kickoff_work()

    def kickoff_work(self):        
        t = WorkerThread(self)
        t.start()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text_display.SetLabel(text)

    def close(self):
        self.Close()

app = wx.App()
DM1Frame = DM1(None, size = (800, 600))
DM1Frame.Center()
DM1Frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try making a global variable that gets the time when it first starts, then having a second variable get the current time and see if the two times are far enough apart to work. Something like this:

When the text changes to something new,

```
global timestart

timestart = gettime()
```

Then, where you check if you are changing the code,

```
timestop = gettime()

if timestop - timestart >= timebetweenchanges:
    change code
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't use a timer for this. They seem to be made for the exact purpose you need them for. As acattle mentioned already, I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) on the subject.

He is completely right though. Using time.sleep() will freeze the GUI because it blocks wx's main event loop. If you absolutely HAVE to use time.sleep() (which I doubt), then you can use a thread. I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) on that subject too. In fact, I actually use time.sleep() in that example.

Comment: Hi @Mike!

Thanks for the answers. I have read your Mouse vs Python blog and it have been very usefull learning python. Currently, I'm figuring how to rewrite my code to use timers. `time.sleep()` appear to be a good approach because it makes my code more clear and parsimonious, but I didn't know that it will freeze the complete GUI. Also, I have been searching for an alternative to `after` of Tkinter, but fruitlessly. According to @user1429351, @acattle and your post, I finally rewrite my code to use `wx.Timer`.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest you go use `wx.CallLater`. Refer to official doc: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html

> A convenience class for wx.Timer, that calls the given callable object
>   once after the given amount of milliseconds, passing any positional or
>   keyword args. The return value of the callable is availbale after it
>   has been run with the GetResult method.
>
> If you don't need to get the return value or restart the timer then
>   there is no need to hold a reference to this object. It will hold a
>   reference to itself while the timer is running (the timer has a
>   reference to self.Notify) but the cycle will be broken when the timer
>   completes, automatically cleaning up the wx.CallLater object.

Possible further reference can be found in this question: [Using wx.CallLater in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851824/using-wx-calllater-in-wxpython)